# Command to get count of list of user account locked,unlocked, expired

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I have these three commands to get count of  number of users,number user account locked,number of user account unlocked, number of password set to never expire.

```
    cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd|wc -l
    cat /etc/passwd | cut -d : -f 1 | awk '{ system("passwd -S " $0) }'|wc -l
 awk -F: '{ system("passwd -S " $1)}' /etc/passwd | grep " PS "|wc -l
    cut -f 1 -d: /etc/passwd | xargs -n 1 -I {} bash -c ' echo -n {}" "; chage -l {} | fgrep "Password expires"' | column -t|wc -l
```

Is there a way where i can addan echo command to it  and /or use one command to get all these info and also get info of account set to expired?
echo "Number of users= xx" ,number of user account locked=xx,number of user password set to never expire=xx,number of user set to expired?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can combine two of the three pretty easily (user count and locked account count) with an `awk`ed `passwd -Sa`, but you'll have to rope in a loop around `chage` to show expired passwords.

```
passwd -Sa |  awk 'BEGIN {lockedusers=0} $2 ~ /L/ {lockedusers++} END {print "Total users:",NF;print "Locked users:",lockedusers}'
neuser=0
for user in $(cut -f1 -d: /etc/passwd); do 
   if chage -l "$user" | grep -i '^Password expires' | grep -q never; then 
      neuser=$((neuser+1))
   fi
done
echo "Non-expiring users: $neuser"
```

If your implementation of `passwd` lacks `-a` (e. g. Red Hat-derived distributions), you can use a similar `for` loop:

```
neuser=0
for user in $(cut -f1 -d: /etc/passwd); do
   if chage -l "$user" | grep -i '^Password expires' | grep -q never; then
      neuser=$((neuser+1))
   fi
   passwd -S "$user"
done | awk 'BEGIN {lockedusers=0} $2 ~ /L/ {lockedusers++} END {print "Total users:",NF;print "Locked users:",lockedusers}'
echo "Non-expiring users: $neuser"
```

Comment: i tried this and i am getting error
passwd: bad argument -Sa: unknown option
Total users: 0
Locked users: 0
Non-expiring users: 22

Comment: Strange, it worked on my system.  Try `passwd -S -a`?

Comment: gives me error  passwd: bad argument -a: unknown option
Total users: 0
Locked users: 0
Non-expiring users: 22

Comment: i am running this script on RHEL

Comment: locked account==33, never expired=46.Getiing wrong ouput due ti failed passwd command i believe

Comment: as copied, it doesn't pick up my user account as the one non-expiring user where i set password expiration to -1 for myself.  This is on SLES 11.4.  If the column output of the `passwd -Sa` command differs between distributions then that will be a hurdle.  Otherwise the script is pretty nifty.

Comment: Indeed, it seems `passwd` differs from Debian-derived distributions such as mine (which has `-Sa`), and on RHEL-derived, which lacks `-a`.  On those hosts, a similar `for|cut` loop should do the trick.

Comment: your `Password expires` needs a capital E -->  `grep '^Password Expires'` for me, and a capital N on `Never`

Comment: Fixed with `grep -i` to catch `Expires` and `expires`.

Comment: @DopeGhoti is there a way to adjust this script with for for|cut loop as it doesnt work RHEL based it lacks -a?

Comment: I have incorporated that adjustment in a second example edited into my original answer.

Answer (score 0):

Below script will return the list of user which are expired and which are going to expired in next 7 days.

```
cat /etc/shadow | cut -d: -f1,8 | sed /:$/d > /tmp/expirelist.txt
totalaccounts=`cat /tmp/expirelist.txt | wc -l`
for((i=1; i<=$totalaccounts; i++ ))
do
    tuserval=`head -n $i /tmp/expirelist.txt | tail -n 1`
    username=`echo $tuserval | cut -f1 -d:`
    userexp=`echo $tuserval | cut -f2 -d:`
    userexpireinseconds=$(( $userexp * 86400 ))
    todaystime=`date +%s`
    #check if the user expired or not?
    if [ $userexpireinseconds -ge $todaystime ] ;
    then
        timeto7days=$(( $todaystime + 604800 ))
    if [ $userexpireinseconds -le $timeto7days ];
    then
        echo "The user account $username going to expired in next 7 days"
    fi
    else
        echo  "The user account $username already expired"
    fi
done
```